# How to upload large file (~100mb) to Azure blob storage using Python SDK?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am using the latest Azure Storage SDK (azure-storage-blob-12.7.1). It works fine for smaller files but throwing exceptions for larger files > 30MB.

> azure.core.exceptions.ServiceResponseError: ('Connection aborted.',
> timeout('The write operation timed out'))

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, PublicAccess, BlobProperties,ContainerClient

    def upload(file):
        settings = read_settings()
        connection_string = settings['connection_string']
        container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(connection_string,'backup')
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file)
        with open(file,"rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
            print(f'{file} uploaded to blob storage')
    
    upload('crashes.csv')
```

Comment: hi, could this be the issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/228 or perhaps https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12166

Comment: I think those are old and closed.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12166 seems an accurate description of your issue, please comment on it to help prioritize the work (I work at MS on the SDK team)

Comment: @LaurentMazuel I have commented on GitHub as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems everything works for me by your code when I tried to upload a ~180MB .txt file. But if uploading small files work for you, I think uploading your big file in small parts could be a workaround. Try the code below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

storage_connection_string=''
container_name = ''
dest_file_name = ''

local_file_path = ''

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string,container_name,dest_file_name)

#upload 4 MB for each request
chunk_size=4*1024*1024  

if(blob_client.exists):
    blob_client.delete_blob()
    blob_client.create_append_blob()

with open(local_file_path, "rb") as stream:
    
    while True:
            read_data = stream.read(chunk_size)
            
            if not read_data:
                print('uploaded')
                break 
            blob_client.append_block(read_data)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs ! But as per the SDK spec the API should handle the chunk internally. So trying to figure out why the API not working as expected! I think as mentioned above SDK team already has got a similar issue active.

Comment: @DevMonk, I see, let's see what is the root reason.

Comment: @DevMonk,bu the way, does the solution: set max_single_put_size to a smaller value  works for you?

Comment: Isn't that param 'max_single_put_size' part of legacy SDK  ?

Comment: @DevMon, actually, it also be part of V12 SDK too, go to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python and search max_block_size or max_single_put_size, you can find them.

Comment: And for upload_blob function, I think you can also extend the timeout config:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#upload-blob-data--blob-type--blobtype-blockblob---blockblob----length-none--metadata-none----kwargs-

Comment: those params didn't resolve the issue. I am going with your approach of chunking. (But the underlying issue is still there, which Azure SDK team needs to resolve)

Comment: I am still getting the timeout issue as well. the append seems to work for me.

Comment: I tried this solution but its taking 2 minutes to upload 50MB, is this normal? It's taking something about 8 sconds everytime it goes to line blob_client.append_block(read_data)

Comment: I decided to use max_block_size and max_single_put_size, and this seems to lessen the timeouts when LTE network is slow.